# Windows cannot find the file specified while running an exe from .bat file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, exe

I am trying to run a exe from a .bat file
However, it throws the above error every time I run the .bat file in powershell.

In both the cmd and powershell window it works properly when I navigate to inside the folder and then run the exe file.

My bat file looks like this.
final1.bat

```
START /w "H:\trunk-2017-10-16" Bootstrapper.exe
```

Anything I could be missing?

Comment: Why do you need to run that batch file from PowerShell? You can dispense with the batch file and run the command you want directly from PowerShell.

Comment: the ps file for the same operation works correctly. but I want a .bat file.

Comment: running it from cmd too produces the same error

Comment: You don't need a .bat file. Just type the command line you want to run and press Enter. Or put the command line in a .ps1 script file and run that. Or create a PowerShell function that contains the command you want and run the function. The batch file is superfluous.

Comment: I need the commands to be in a file.. to be triggered at once. This is only the first step .. hence the batch file. Thanks anyway. The issue is resolved now.

Comment: If the command needs to be in a file, put it in a .ps1 file (PowerShell script file). You don't need a batch file. (Running a batch file means you have to spawn cmd.exe. A .ps1 script will run more quickly.)

Comment: the file has to be compatible with older versions of the clients system. Hence a .bat file

Comment: PowerShell is a default part of the OS starting in Windows 7.

Comment: I get the impression based on your executable name that the `/wait` option is almost pointless. A bootstrapper generally passes to another executable file, once it has done that it closes and passes control back to your batch file. Your batch file will then continue despite the other executable process not being finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your executable file is `"H:\trunk-2017-10-16\Bootstrapper.exe"`

Then you'd need

```
START /w "" "H:\trunk-2017-10-16\Bootstrapper.exe"
```

Note that the first quoted argument becomes the window-title.

OR, if you really want "H:\trunk-2017-10-16" to be your window-title, then `bootstrapper.exe` appears not to be on your `path` at the present time.